# Certbot on nginx not creating .well-known directory on website

Tags: linux, certificate, nginx, letsencrypt, certbot

When trying to install a certificate on an nginx server using `sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w [my web root] -d [mywebsite]` I get this error:

```
   Domain: [mywebsite]
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://mywebsite/.well-known/acme-challenge/[key]
   [ip]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML
   4.01//EN\"\n
   \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n\n<head>\n
   <title>[other code]"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

That code shown is the begining of my index page however invalid 404 pages are given 403 errors and are not redirected to the index.

Comment: Did you create the external DNS txt record with the cerbot acme challenge key or whatever?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT No the server was just created and the first thing done was install letsencrypt the only changes were adding a index.php page and following the instructions on certbot ubuntu nginx.

Comment: You do it differently than I do and I run it from CentOS but, curious to know how you get resolved though. I assume you are configuring so you do not need to update any external DNS txt records, but I think the actual server needs to be able to come back in and resolve though so I think that error message regarding the "*please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.*" is telling you the problem?

Comment: Read over the [**"To use Certbot, you'll need..."**](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx) section and confirm that you have these things in place for a starting point.